# Как растянуть изображение на весь экран в PhotoView?

Tags: java, android, photoview

Есть компонент

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/ivScr0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    />
```

Загружаю изображение

```
ivScr0.setImageBitmap(myImg)
```

Если изображение меньше экрана, то остаются поля. 
Как увеличить изображение до размеров экрана?

Comment: `scaleType` пробовали ставить?

Comment: не понимаю где и как указать scaleType. Можно пример?

Comment: В xml атрибут `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. Или другое значение, которое вам подойдёт. [Что такое scaleType?](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php#scaletype)

Comment: да, нашел где, перепробовал, но не помогло пока

Comment: получилось решить проблему, если указывать параметр не в xml. Например так: ivScr0.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

Comment: Отлично. Опишите это в виде ответа. Будет полезно для других участников сообщества.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытка прописать scalrType в xml файле не привела к нужному результату.

Когда прописал тип в самом коде

```
PhotoView ivScr0;
.....
ivScr0.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

все заработало

Список типов, которые можно использовать:

FIT_CENTER - изображение посередине экрана

FIT_START  - изображение в верхней части контейнера

FIT_END   - изображение в нижней части контейнера

CENTER_CROP - равномерное растягивание картинки, заполняется весь контейнер с обрезкой.

FIT_XY - растягивание/сжимание картинки (заполнение контейнера полностью)

MATRIX - без изменения размеров, выводится в левый верхний угол.